# CASE statement in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbaddress
(aid integer identity not null, link_id int, link_type char, primary key (aid))
CREATE TABLE dbDoorSupervisor
(did integer identity not null, name varchar(30), primary key (did))
CREATE TABLE dbLicensee
(lid integer identity not null, name varchar(30), primary key (lid))

INSERT INTO dbDoorSupervisor (name) values ('Ian')
INSERT INTO dbLicensee (name) values ('Maria')
INSERT INTO dbaddress (link_id, link_type) values (1,'D')
INSERT INTO dbaddress (link_id, link_type) values (1,'L')
```

I am trying to get the name of the Door Supervisor or Licensee depending on the Address.AID that is supplied.  For example, if aid 1 is supplied in the WHERE clause, then Ian is returned from the door supervisor table, however if aid 2 is supplied in the WHERE clause then Maria is returned from the Licensee table.

I know you can use CASE statements in the SELECT clause, but can you use them in the FROM clause i.e. join from address to licensee or address to door supervisor depending on the AID that is supplied?

Comment: No, but you could join in both tables, and then use a CASE in the SELECT to read out only the appropriate linked name for each row. Or, you could do two queries, one that looks for one type and one for the other type, and union them together.

Comment: @JacobM, thanks. I think the answer is to create a derived table containing all door supervisors and licensees as I think you implied.

Answer (score 4):

you can switch in the `left outer join` section like this:

```
select
    isnull(d.name, l.name) as name
from dbaddress as a
    left outer join dbDoorSupervisor as d on d.did = a.link_id and a.link_type = 'D'
    left outer join dbLicensee as l on l.lid = a.link_id and a.link_type = 'L'
```

Or join anyway and switch in the case statement

```
select
    case a.link_type
        when 'D' then d.name
        when 'L' then l.name
    end as name
from dbaddress as a
    left outer join dbDoorSupervisor as d on d.did = a.link_id
    left outer join dbLicensee as l on l.lid = a.link_id
```

If you have more than one column to show, you can use outer apply so you dont' have to repeat case:

```
select
    c.name, c.address, c.second_name
from dbaddress as a
    left outer join dbDoorSupervisor as d on d.did = a.link_id
    left outer join dbLicensee as l on l.lid = a.link_id
    outer apply (
        select d.name, d.second_name, d.address where a.link_type = 'D' union all
        select l.name, l.second_name, l.address where a.link_type = 'L'
    ) as c
```

Comment: As a side note, if there are more than two combinations and you go with the `isnull` route, you could either nest them like `isnull(ds.name, isnull(dl.name, dx.name))` or go with [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: @JoeEnos added solution for more than one columns, it could be easily extended for more than one combination

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.linkd_id,
case when link_type = 'D' then d.name
    when link_type = 'L' then l.name
end as 'Name'
from dbAddress a
left join dbDoorSupervisor d on d.did = a.link_id
left join dbLicensee l on l.lid = a.link_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without dynamic SQL, which has its own set of issues.

If your database is simple like this, with only 2 or so possibilities, one simple way is to join both and deal with the results manually, like:

```
select
    a.aid
    ,case a.link_type
        when 'D' then ds.name
        when 'L' then l.name
    end [name]
from
    dbaddress a
left join
    dbDoorSupervisor ds on a.link_type = 'D' and a.link_id = ds.did
left join
    dbLicensee l on a.link_type = 'L' and a.link_id = l.lid
```

Comment: there's no link_id column in dbDoorSupervisor and dbLicensee in OP schema :)